# Jquery, bind function to selector ( dynamically added) and without any event involved

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using the useful [jquery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) library.

I belive it's better to see it on jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ttttoni/6hv03t57/1/)

I've got a list of items in a shopping-chart-like structure. And a button to add new items in the list. Each item is an input field that uses jquery-Autocomplete. However newly added items do not have the function `autocomplete({...})` bound to them.

HTML:

```
<div class="row-item">
    <input type='text' class='search-me'/>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" id="add-search">+&nbsp;Add new</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){ 
    var countries = [
   { value: 'Andorra', data: 'AD' },
   { value: 'Zimbabwe', data: 'ZZ' },
   { value: 'Denmark', data: 'DK' }
    ];
    // <----------------------------- MAKE THIS BINDING PERMANENT at document level
    $('input.search-me').autocomplete({
        lookup:countries,   
        onSelect: function(suggestion){
            var msg=$('<span />',{class:'msg',text:suggestion.data+' selected'});
            $(this).after(msg);     
            $(msg).fadeOut(2000,function(){
                $(msg).remove();   
            });
        }
    });
    //--------------------------------------------- END
    $('a#add-search').on('click',function(){
        var itemrow=$('div.row-item:first').clone();
        $(itemrow).find('input').val('');
        $('div.row-item:last').after(itemrow);
    });
});
```

I'd like bind the function `autocomplete` to all elements (actual or newly generated) with `class=search-me`, at document level.

Similarly to when one binds a function given an event:

`$(document).on('click','#selectorid',myfunction)`

Comment: Why don't you just bind autocomplete when you create the element? P.S.: IDs must be unique, so when cloning, change the id of the input.

Comment: Yes! I could do that, but I want it bound at document level. For code simplicity. This is actually a problem I bump into quite often lately. You are right about the ID, a class would be a better choice(edited).

Comment: I don't think what you want to achieve is possible, but you can make use of [`DOMNodeInserted`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php) event which will trigger when you insert something in the DOM. You can then active your auto complete here. The support is not so good though... If support is a problem, you could use `setInterval`, but then, it will take extra juice.... The best solution is really to activate it when appending.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with poor IE support:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'someID') {
       //element with #someID was inserted.
       // your autocomplete code here
    }
    if ($(e.target).is('.someClass')) {
       //element with class someClass was inserted.
       // your autocomplete code here
    }
});
```